# converting to time series using ts() in r

Tags: r

Good afternoon

I have a time series

```
v2<-c(12,13,15,17,18,12,11,12)
```

which run from July 1996 to October 1997, just the months between July and October

when I try to convert to time series with

```
v2.ts<-ts(v2, frequency=12, start=c(1996,7), end=c(1997,10))
```

It yields me this result

```
    Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
1996                        12  13  15  17  18  12

1997 11  12  12  13  15  17  18  12  11  12
```

what parameters can I use to make it like:

```
     Jul Aug Sep Oct 
1996  12  13  15  17

1997  18  12  11  12
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 1):

A ts series must be regularly spaced but the output shown has points that are one month apart except between Oct of the first year and July of the second year so it is not of that form.

There are several packages that can represent irregularly spaced series.  With the zoo package it would be done like this:

```
library(zoo)

z <- as.zoo(v2.ts)
z[cycle(z) %in% 7:10]
## Jul 1996 Aug 1996 Sep 1996 Oct 1996 Jul 1997 Aug 1997 Sep 1997 Oct 1997 
##      12       13       15       17       18       12       11       12
```

If you are not looking for a time series but just a matrix with the indicated elements then:

```
tapply(c(v2.ts), list(floor(time(v2.ts)), cycle(v2.ts)), c)[, 7:10]

##       7  8  9 10
## 1996 12 13 15 17
## 1997 18 12 11 12
```